# Unity fails to build and shows a gradle error for android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

I am using Unity on a mac and trying to build my game on Android.
The project builds fine on iOS and this is the first time i am trying to build it on Android.
I get 2 errors - they seem to be related to `gradle`.

```
Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

Failed to run '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BQvF/BQ/Temp/PlayServicesResolverGradle/gradlew --no-daemon -b "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BQvF/BQ/Temp/PlayServicesResolverGradle/PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.2f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/BQvF/BQ/Assets/Plugins/Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1;com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1;com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1;com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1;com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0;com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[7.1.0, 8);com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:[7.1.0, 8);com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[7.1.0, 8);com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[7.1.0, 8);com.facebook.android:facebook-gamingservices:[7.1.0, 8)" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=0" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=3.6.0"'
stdout:

stderr:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
    
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create an instance of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings_Decorated.
> Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

And the second error is

```
Unable to determine which Android packages are installed.
Failed to run '/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2020.1.2f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list --verbose'
stdout:

stderr:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more

exit code: 1
```

Comment: do you have installed AndroidStudio, with the corresponding SDK, NDK etc?

Comment: @Lotan - I do have AndroidStudio installed, however not sure how i can check if i have the corresponding SDK / NDK?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this i did 2 things:

1. updated Gradle to 5.5.1, and
2. Unity didnt recognise the newer Java I installed. So i deleted all JDKs, and then only installed 1.8

Works like a charm

Comment: please mark your answer as correct so everyone else with the same problem can see it easily

Answer (score 0):

Did you install NDK? Go to preferences in unity and check whether you have the path for NDK i'll provide a link for a tutorial on how to build an apk
You can watch that check whether you are doing everything correctly or not
https://youtu.be/j0L3SDYyMJI

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go and let you know - would you know what NDK version i need to be using for Unity 2020.1.2f1? The docs don't seem to say that?

Comment: Also - im not sure its an NDK issue? It seems to be something to do with Gradle?

Comment: I used 16.F or something like that you can use the one that he is using in the video or else use the NDK that is installed with the unity and FYI google play doesnt accept 32 bit games from now on so we will need NDK to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Custom Keystore in Project Settings -> Player -> Publishing Settings, enter your passwords in the both fields.
Then go to Assets -> External Dependency Manager -> Android Resolver ->  Force Resolve.